# phrases that express "where somethign is going to"

Tags: phrase-choice

In this sentence "Government pay close attentions [where the inflation is going to]".I have problem to epxress [which level/point the inflaiont will reach to] in this sentence,
I am wondering if any expression fits better for the content in the bracket? Maybe "where the inflation is lead to", or  "where the inflation is getting up to" or any other expression is better?

Comment: The lines within brackets, have you picked them up from some written text, or have you yourself created them? I ask because there are spelling and grammatical mistakes in  those lines.

Comment: @banuyayi: Hi banuyayi, I wrote this actually. Yeah, I see there are other mistakes also, like "attentions" should be attention. But I am more inclined to figure out the right expression in the bracket since similar meaning may be useful in reports.

Comment: Please edit your question if you want to not waste other forum members'  time. If you do want to waste  other forum members'  time leave it as it is.

Comment: ***Governments** pay close **attention to** where inflation is going*. There are many governments, and ***attention*** is an uncountable noun. The reason for discarding that final ***to*** after ***going*** is nothing to do with the fact that the same preposition occurs after ***attention*** earlier in the utterance. We wouldn't include it in *We don't know where inflation is going* either. Note that this is a *metaphoric* use of ***to go*** - in more literal contexts, such as *He just went out, but I don't know where he was going [to]*, the preposition is more likely (but still unnecessary).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thank you so much, FumbleFingers, I understand the incorrect words and expressions in this sentence. I really appreciate your help~~~

Answer (score 2):

You would probably say something like:

> where inflation is heading

> where inflation is headed

> where inflation is going